# Complex Roots and calculations

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis

roots of the equation $z^6 =1-\sqrt3 i $ 
are $$z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5,z_6 $$

calculate:$$|z_1|^3  +|z_2|^3+|z_3|^3+|z_4|^3+|z_5|^3+|z_6|^3$$

also calculate: $$z_1^6  +z_2^6+z_3^6+z_4^6+z_5^6+z_6^6$$

Prove that the roots of the equation form a geometric progression and find it's $q$.

Find the Sum of the six roots of the eqaution.

Attempt to Solve:

This question is bewildering, I have no idea where to start...the notion of power of complex number in this context is also quite vague

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$z^6=1-\sqrt{3}i=2\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i\right)=2e^{-\frac{\pi}{3}i}$$
For the first computations you don't even need to compute the roots: $|z_k|=\sqrt[6]{2}$ and trivially $z_k^6=1-\sqrt{3}i$,
$$|z_1|^3  +|z_2|^3+|z_3|^3+|z_4|^3+|z_5|^3+|z_6|^3=6(\sqrt[6]{2})^3=6\sqrt{2}$$
and
$$z_1^6  +z_2^6+z_3^6+z_4^6+z_5^6+z_6^6=6(1-\sqrt{3}i)\ .$$
Now, the roots are 
$$z_{k}=\sqrt[6]{2}e^{i\left(-\frac{\pi}{18}+k\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}=\sqrt[6]{2}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{18}}\left(e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}\right)^k$$
The sum is thus:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{5}\sqrt[6]{2}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{18}}\left(e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}\right)^k=\sqrt[6]{2}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{18}}\sum_{k=0}^{5}\left(e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}\right)^k=\sqrt[6]{2}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{18}}\frac{1-(e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}})^{5+1}}{1-e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}}=0$$

Comment: pretty neat....

Comment: how did you do calc 2 ?

Comment: Do you mean the 2 I collected in the first step?

Comment: I mean; $$z_1^6  +z_2^6+z_3^6+z_4^6+z_5^6+z_6^6=6(1-\sqrt{3}i)\ .$$

Comment: For each $z_{k}$ you have $z_{k}^6=1-\sqrt{3}i$ (since they are solutions of your equations): you are just summing 6 of them.

Comment: yeah I know but you somehow did it at once and with no steps...

Comment: One you notice that other steps seem redundant: if you really want you can write $$z_1^6  +z_2^6+z_3^6+z_4^6+z_5^6+z_6^6=1-\sqrt{3}i+1-\sqrt{3}i+1-\sqrt{3}i+1-\sqrt{3}i+1-\sqrt{3}i+1-\sqrt{3}i=6(1-\sqrt{3}i)\ .$$

Comment: $Z_k$ should be in fact depnded on k, however since k is some integer repeat of 2pi we can disregard it? therefore $Z_k = \6sqrt 2 * e^-i/pi/3 $?

Comment: No, the point is that $z_k$ is indeed $k$-dependent but once you take the 6th power the factor $e^{ik\pi/3}$ becomes $e^{2 ik\pi}=1$ and thus $z_k^{\color{red}{6}}$ is independent of $k$.

Comment: i*2pik + (-pi/3).. but adding 2pi, 4pi, etc, returns same angel so....we get same angel...?

Comment: Yes, but the ones with $+2k\pi i$ at the exponent are $z_{k}^6$ not $z_{k}$: $z_{k}$ have $+2k\pi i/3$ at the exponent.

Comment: sorry mr dario this gone a bit south, let me explain myself:$z_k^6 =2*e^i(-pi/3 +2pik) = 2*e^-i*pi/3 *e^(i2pik)  = 2*e^-i*pi/3 *(cos2pik + isin2pik) = 2*e^-i*pi/3  $ since for any k $(cos2pik + isin2pik)$ will evalute to one , and hence your said calculation is achieved..is this correct?

Comment: This is fine: it is a bit lengthy since you can avoid that calculations, but it is indeed correct.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**.

1. For the first question, given that $z^6=1-\sqrt3 i$, can you find $|z|$ without finding $z$?
2. For the second question, what does it actually mean to say that $z_1$ is a root of the equation?
3. For the fourth question, what do you know about the sum of the roots of a real polynomial?  The same is true for a complex polynomial.

If you find complex powers "bewildering" you probably should start with some simpler problems.  For example, given $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1-i)$, find $z^2$ and $z^{23}$ and $z^{234}$.  Also, solve the equations $z^2=-1$ and $z^2=i$ and $z^4=i$.

Comment: im usually ok with ciomplex numbers, this exercise is a little differnt though...I apprciate your plan though..

Answer (score 1):

The second sum is easy. All the roots satisfy $z^6=1-\sqrt{3}i$, hence
$$\sum_{i=1}^6z_i^6=6(1-\sqrt{3}i)$$
Also,
$$z^6=2e^{-i\pi/6} \Rightarrow z=2^{1/6}e^{-i(\pi/3+2k\pi)}$$
where $k=0,1,2,3,4,5$
The modulus of each root is hence $2^{1/6}$ i.e
$$\sum_{i=1}^6|z_i|^3=6\cdot 2^{1/2}$$